# Mathematica frequently stops responding

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Every time I run a cell, move the cursor, start typing, the entirety of Mathematica stops responding.
I am getting "Disable dynamic evaluation" pop ups but I have disabled Dynamic in the option inspector as well as deselcted it under the Evaluation menu.

This makes it very frustrating to work with Mathematica as every change I make takes up to 10 seconds before I can do anything.

Is there some way I can overcome this?
I am using Mathematica 13.0.

Comment: What are your system specs? More importantly, how capable is your video card?

Comment: Is there a typical computation that causes this?

Comment: Apparently related/duplicate: [**Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/4999)

Comment: Although the poster has reported that it's solved, I still want to point it out that this phenomenon can be produced under a number of situations, even for the new installation of Mathematica. And I still find it hard to diagnose some of them today.

Answer (score 4):

It seems disabling the Suggestions Bar through "Preferences->Interface->Show Suggestions Bar after Last output" has solved the issue.